# How do I create partitions for a dual boot (Ubuntu then Windows) on a new HDD?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I’m not familiar with Linux at the moment.  I have a new desktop with a 1TB HDD.  I’ve installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 on it and am trying to create a partition for a later installation of a Windows OS.

I downloaded Gparted but can’t get it to do what I want as I can’t unmount the partition with the lion’s share of the disk.  Even if I generate another boot/install DVD with Gparted on it I’m not sure it’ll do what I want.

Gparted gives my present configuration as:

```
Partition   Name                    File System  Mount Point    Size    Flags
/dev/sda1   EFI System Partition    Fat32        /boot/efi      512MB   Boot,esp
/dev/sda2                           Ext4         /              923GB   
/dev/sda3                           Linux-swap                  7.92GB
```

I would also like to share files between both OS’s.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) Are you open to solutions involving a Virtual Machine? I use Windows 10 every day...in a VM. 2) 16.04 is quite old and reaches End Of Life next year. Consider installing 20.04, which has five years of community support. 3) You cannot run Gparted on a partition that is mounted. Boot from your Live Installer instead, and use Gparted from there.

Comment: It is best to install Windows first, it will create partitions and you can use Windows disk manager to shrink Windows and create space for Ubuntu. You can use GParted on a Live USB to add partitions to the drive. 100GB might be enough for Ubuntu. Don't use GParted on a Windows partition.

Comment: user535733.  1) I'd rather not use a VM.  2). I tried to use a later version of Linux on USB but failed to find any s/w that would extract the ISO. I tried 4 or 5 different programmes then gave up and put in a DVD I'd created a while back :-). I'm happy for Ubuntu to update after installation. 3) Not sure how to do that & not sure I'll get what I'm after.

Comment: C S Cameron. Yes I think installing Windows first maybe the simplest solution.  Not sure how to get Gparted on a live USB, is there a link to a free download? Any problems with arranging it to support file sharing?  Many thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: user535733.  Many thanks for your quick reply, much appreciated.

Comment: With newer UEFI systems, after 2012 you want UEFI installs to gpt partitioned drives. How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs, so always boot in UEFI boot mode. Windows in UEFI/gpt mode wants lots of partitions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations So best to let Windows create its own partition in unallocated space.

Comment: GParted Download: https://gparted.org/download.php, GParted Install: https://gparted.org/liveusb.php, Use UNetbootin method. GParted is also located on the Ubuntu Live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to all those that have responded to my question.  I followed most of @heynnema's methodology to successfully create a dual-boot system.  Having read other posts as well I decided to install Windows 10 first.

Here follows my methodology:
1.  Install Windows 10 first.
2.  Open Disk Management.  To do this type ‘create and format hard disk partitions’ into the search box.  Make sure that the file system is NTFS.
3.  In the graphical area right click in the area you want to shrink for the Ubuntu installation.
4.  Left click ‘Shrink Volume’
5.  Enter amount required in the highlighted box.
6.  Left click ‘Shrink’
7.  Reboot to BIOS.
8.  Disable ‘Secure Boot’.
9.  Boot to Ubuntu using DVD or USB.
10. Install Ubuntu alongside Windows.
11. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Start over, and do this...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB (something newer than 16.04)
- using `gparted`, lay down a fresh GPT partition table (this will wipe the disk) if a UEFI computer, or MBR partition table (this will wipe the disk) if a BIOS computer
- boot to a Windows install disc
- install a fresh Windows installation
- boot to Windows
- in Windows, disable Fast Boot and hibernation
- using Windows `Disk Management` application, shrink the C: drive partition
- using Windows `Disk Management` application, create a new NTFS partition to share files
- in your BIOS, disable Secure Boot
- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB (something newer than 16.04)
- install Ubuntu "Along side of Windows"
- reboot the computer

Comment: heynnema,  Many thanks for your reply.  I’ve got a Windows 10 DVD on order so when it arrives I’ll run through your steps.

Comment: @WoodenHorse Why don't you download the .iso yourself and burn your own DVD? Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: heynnema.  I thought I'd need a license key.

Comment: @WoodenHorse you may. If you had a working, licensed copy of Windows installed before, it probably saved the key in your BIOS, and reinstalling will pick that up. Otherwise check for a sticker on your computer with the key. Or, purchase a key... they go for around $10-$15.

Comment: @WoodenHorse ps: download the .iso for the same version of Windows that was previously installed.

Comment: This is a PC I built from the ground up, so no OS installed.  I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 laptop as a trial run, worked fine so hopefully when I get my Windows 10 disk I’ll be able to repeat the operation.  Again many thanks for your replies and for your time in helping me.

Comment: @WoodenHorse Did you order your Windows 10 disc with a key? If you're able to follow my procedure, and it was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes its supposed to be coming with a key.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already found a solution. But, I just did myself and it is easy peasy.
Scenario:
You already have Ubuntu on your HDD and you want to install windows 10.

1. goto gparted.org
2. download .iso file from gparted
3. download balenaEtcher an open source iso burner
4. create bootable gparted usb
5. boot your machine with USB
6. follow simple instructions, I used graphic mode of gparted.
7. Partition your HDD
8. Format your HDD to windows file system
9. you can now install windows 10 either from windows usb or cd or even from ubuntu directly. (i haven't tried directly from ubuntu, I personally use USB)

Good luck to all those who may come here looking for same solution.